# Disable entire cache for development

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm developing a new theme for Drupal 8. I need to disable all caching mechanisms in Drupal. I found the configuration for twig caching and CSS/JavaScript but not for other things of Drupal (like `.theme` files, etc.).

I found some hints here:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/8
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2239909

In the first linkt you find some entries beginning with `cache.` and in the second link how to deactivate probably the backend cache?

Although if I paste those two lines:

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/development.services.yml';
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

into my `settings.php` Drupal shows a message that there has been an error with the page.

Answer (score 14):

to disable entire cache (twig + Drupal cache) :

first copy and rename the `sites/example.settings.local.php` to be sites/default/settings.local.php

```
$ cp sites/example.settings.local.php sites/default/settings.local.php
```

then open `settings.php` file in `sites/default` and  uncomment these lines:

```
# if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
#   include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
# }
```

now open `settings.local.php` and change the to be `TRUE`

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
```

and uncomment all these to Disable the render cache and  Disable Dynamic Page Cache

```
# $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
# $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

for twig cache open `development.services.yml` and add

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug : true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

for more info https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

Comment: After this I've gotten this error : `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "cache.backend.null".`
To fix this just go to : *http://yoursite/core/rebuild.php*

Comment: Changing the `(...)['preprocess'] = FALSE;` lines to `TRUE` breaks serving my CSS files, I had to revert it.

Comment: If you get `non-existent service "cache.backend.null"` error you have not included `development.services.yml` which defines that service.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Mix (https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module to disable all these caches with just one click. No manual editing works.
[image]